# Mysqli: skip update if variable is NULL

Tags: php, mysqli

Is it possible to skip update if variable is NULL?

Query:

```
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE personal SET name=?, gender=?, telp=?, address=?, date_deadline=? WHERE id_personal=?");
  $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $nm, $gd, $tl, $ar, $dt, $id);
```

Here, I want to skip date_deadline field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE personal 
SET name=?, gender=?, telp=?, address=?,
    date_deadline = case when ? is null 
                         then date_deadline
                         else ? 
                    end
WHERE id_personal = ?

$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $nm, $gd, $tl, $ar, $dt, $dt, $id);
```

Comment: Somehow we need to modify bind_param() too, because now I get: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Comment: I added that to the answer. Since you have the `$dt` parameter 2 times now

Answer (score 1):

From how you've explained your question the answer seems very simple, try the following:

```
if (is_null($myVar)) {
    // Code to run if null.
} else {
    // Update query here.
}
```

**Edit 1:**

If you don't want to run any code if it *is* null. Then do the following:

```
if (!is_null($myVar)) {
    // Code to run if not null.
}
```